# Run Specific File instead of Current File in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I've seen some answers on Stack Overflow about how to automatically run one specific file in Visual Studio *Code* but not in Visual Studio. How can I not have it default to the current opened file when I run files in **Visual Studio**?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is right-click on the desired file in the Solution Explorer and select Set as Startup Item. I've only tried this with Python, but I don't see why it wouldn't work with any other code file.